# how to configure Spring Integration to read from Redis with multithread?

Tags: spring, multithreading, redis, spring-integration

I'm setting up a Spring Integration configuration to read from redis with multithread but when I run my application, Spring only creates one thread.

I am creating an int-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter with an executor-task with pool-size= 500 and queue-capacity=0.

```xml
<redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter
            id="fromRedis" channel="privateAggregationExecutorChannel" queue="${instance}_private"
            receive-timeout="1000" recovery-interval="3000" expect-message="false" error-channel="distributionErrors"
            auto-startup="false" task-executor="robotTaskExecutor"/>

<task:executor
            id="robotTaskExecutor"
            pool-size="500"
            queue-capacity="0"
            keep-alive="50"
            rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="privateAggregationExecutorChannel" ref="aggregationExecutor" method="run" />
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if there is something that I'm missing. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. The `RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint` is really single-threaded component:

```
@Override
protected void doStart() {
    if (!this.active) {
        this.active = true;
        this.restart();
    }
}

private void restart() {
    this.taskExecutor.execute(new ListenerTask());
}
```

As you see only one `ListenerTask` is scheduled from this channel adapters.

To make it multi-threaded, it is better to have an `ExecutorChannel` to send messages from this channel adapter. This way even if  `RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint` is a single-threaded one, you're still going to have a multi-threaded processing.

We just realized that it is going to be a bit complicated to introduce a concurrency into this component when we can workaround other simple way.

Another approach is to have several `<redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter>` definitions for the same `queue` and `same` channel to send.